# Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}{[({1\over e}(1+{1\over x})^x)]^x}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}{[({1\over e}(1+{1\over x})^x)]^x}$. 
I have been trying for hours using the continuity of $e$ and using L'Hopital rule but it gets really scattered and ugly. I am in despaire. I would really, truly, appreciate your help.

Comment: Maple answers ${{\rm e}^{-1/2}}. $

Comment: Yes, that, I know, but I want to know how to get there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the Taylor expansion of $\log(1+z)$ in a neighbourhood of zero, when $x\to +\infty$ we have:
$$ x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-1 = -\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)\tag{1}$$
so, exponentiating the previous identity,
$$\frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = 1-\frac{1}{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \tag{2}$$
and by raising both terms to the $x$-power:
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(\frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x\right)^x = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2x}\right)^x = \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: I am really new to Taylor series, and I try to understand: 1. why did you move "1" to the other side, how does it help you?
2. Shouldn't it be ${1\over 3x^2}$?

Comment: @Meitar: about the second point, you're right, now fixed. I moved $1$ to the other side since I wanted an $\frac{1}{e}$ to appear in the next line.

Comment: Okay. I am a bit slow, but I start to get it. Now, $\frac{1}{e}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e^{x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)-1}$ but how can it become simply $1-\frac{1}{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) $?

Comment: It is easy by exploiting $A^x = \exp(x \log A) = 1+x\log A+O(x\log A)^2$ and $\log A = \log(1-B) = -B+O(B^2)$.

Comment: That's so confusing... Then does it mean I have to develop $\log (-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right))$?

Comment: @Meitar , you just have to show that $$e^A=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{A}{x}\right)^x = \lim_{x\to +\infty}\left(1+\frac{A}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)^x.$$

Comment: I have $e^{(-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{3x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right))}$ and I want it to become $1-\frac{1}{2x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$... Right for now, I can't seem to make it happen. I understand your direction but I won't make the connection. I am sorry, maybe I am too inert for this kind of operations but I would really want to know what I am doing here.

Comment: Are you saying you were using $e$ Taylor series? @Jack

Comment: @Meitar: yes, just exploit $e^A = 1+A+O(A^2).$

Comment: @Meitar: you're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Note $f(x) = {[({1\over e}(1+{1\over x})^x)]^x}$, then $\log(f(x)) = - x \log (e) + x \log \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x \right) = -x + x^2 \log\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right) = x^2 \left( \log\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right) - \frac{1}{x}\right) $ and as when $x$ then to $+\infty$ the quantity $\log\left( 1+\frac{1}{x}\right) - \frac{1}{x}$ is equivalent to $-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2$ (develop $\log(1+u)$ at the second order in $u$ as $u\to 0$) you find that $\log(f(x)) \to -\frac{1}{2}$, and taking the $\exp$ gives you that $f(x) \to e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: There is no log in here?

Comment: @Meitar I wrote "take the $\log$". You are looking for $\lim f(x)$, I am advising you to look at $\lim \log(f(x))$, to calculate it, and to use continuity of $\exp$ to get back the value of $\lim f(x)$

Comment: I tried to but it gets messy.

Comment: @Meitar So that you want us to clean up the "mess"... I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: try taylor, which is usually more doable than L'Hospital.
Hint 2: Try the logarithm. Calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln [\frac{1}{e}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]^x$ first
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln [\frac{1}{e}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}[x^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-x]$$
Since $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$
$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x^2}+o(\frac{1}{x^2})$$
Therefore
$$x^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-x=-\frac{1}{2}+o(\frac{1}{x})$$
Or
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}[x^2\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})-x]=\lim_{x\to\infty}[-\frac{1}{2}+o(\frac{1}{x})]=\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln [\frac{1}{e}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]^x=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Which yields
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}[\frac{1}{e}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x]^x=e^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$